# error: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I keep trying to install the entity framework 6 and it always rolls back with the error of

```
error: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
```

I've uninstalled all the references to every dll mentioned at this location. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6

The crazy thing is that i can create a new project, create a webAPI program, and attempt to add Entity Framework 6 and I get the same error, even after removing all references to **System.Data.Entity.dll** I'm already a few days into this, and needing serious help.

what can i do to get Entity Framework 6 to install?

Note: It will install just find to a class library just not a WebApi or MVC application.

---

If it helps here is some more detailed error info.

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' to AC.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' to AC.
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateNode(XNode node, XNode previous)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddNodeSkipNotify(XNode n)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Add(Object content)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XContainerExtensions.GetOrCreateElement(XContainer container, String elementName, XAttribute[] attributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileManipulator.AddOrUpdateConfigSection(XDocument config, Version entityFrameworkVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__1(XDocument c)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileProcessor.ProcessConfigFile(ProjectItem configItem, IEnumerable`1 manipulators)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__0(ProjectItem i)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileFinder.FindConfigFiles(ProjectItems items, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.Execute()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Same over here..still no solution :-(?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Entity Framework is upgraded, the app.config or web.config files will get stuff written into them. I suspect that might be the problem. Take a look at your app.config or web.config files. Maybe the EF upgrade is having trouble writing to them without making an invalid xml document.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I was adding EF to one of my really old projects and web.config had this namespace defined for `<configuration />` element:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

Removing that namespace declaration (`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`) helped and solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I had same old project and removing namespace helped me too.

Comment: Removing the xmlns from web.config fixes this for me too, i've been trying to install Entity Framework for 2 days and this fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and discovered the cause was the  element in the web.config file. In my case, I changed this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to this:

```
<configuration>
```

That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is to do with your configuration files. Just to detail the solution I found:

First save your app.config, packages.config and web.config

Then delete them all. I actually deleted app.config and packages.config and just cleared out the lines between  and  in the web.config.

Then I ran the Install-Package again, all went well, then I added back in my configuration.

Comment: I had to move `app.config` and `web.config` to a different directory, create an empty `app.config` file, and then manually merge the newly generated data into the existing config files. (Mostly, the generated data was the same.)

Answer (score 1):

In a web app, web.config had a reference to external `app.config`:

```
<appSettings configSource="App.config" />
```

This requires the App.config to be in a particular format, that Entity Framework installer considers invalid.

So, like others, the key was to:

- rename/delete the `App.config`
- Install EF
- bring back the `App.config`

Comment: This solved my problem installing EF6 to a legacy app. I deleted the xmlns from web.config, but also had to temporarily rename app.config for it to work. There wasn't anything obvious in app.config causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I modified my web.config from

```
(<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">)
```

To

```
(<configuration>)
```