# Error Installing Entity Framework 6.0.1 From Nuget (Incorrectly Structured Document)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a .NET 4.5 WebForms Project on Visual Studio 2012. I get an error whenever I try to install Entity Framework through Nuget or the Package Manager Console.  It seems to me that it is having trouble modifying the web.config but I used a web.config validator online and everything checks out. This is a project-specific error and I can't figure out why.  The Error is as follows:

> Installing 'EntityFramework 6.0.1'.
>   Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.0.1'.
>   Executing script file 'C:\Users\Devan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AcclamareWeb\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\init.ps1'.
>   Adding 'EntityFramework 6.0.1' to [PROJECT NAME].
>   Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.0.1' to [PROJECT NAME].
>   Executing script file 'C:\Users\Devan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ [PROJECT NAME]\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\install.ps1'.
>   Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.0.1'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.0.1'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21681056/164187 , maybe it will help

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and discovered the cause was the  element in the web.config file. In my case, I changed this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to this:

```
<configuration>
```

That fixed it.

Comment: Worked for me too in order to install EF through the NuGet command line.

Comment: Worked for me - just had to restart VS after the config change. Thanks!