# Error Installing Entity Framework 6.0.1 From Nuget (This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.)

Tags: entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 I need to use Entity Framework. I have tried installing latest Entity framework through Nuget package, but I am getting the following error below. I have pasted the complete nuget stack error. I have tried several things like un-installing/installing EF, adding EF references manually,etc. but none have worked so far and I have lost 2 days.

```
I have tried links similar to my problem here in this site and even that has not helped and hence starting new thread hoping that someone will help me here! 
Need help here...I am stuck.

Error stack:

Install-Package EntityFramework
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.0'.
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320539. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.0'.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.1.0' to EPP.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.1.0' to EPP.
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateNode(XNode node, XNode previous)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddNodeSkipNotify(XNode n)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Add(Object content)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XContainerExtensions.GetOrCreateElement(XContainer container, String elementName, XAttribute[] attributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileManipulator.AddOrUpdateConfigSection(XDocument config, Version entityFrameworkVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__1(XDocument c)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileProcessor.ProcessConfigFile(ProjectItem configItem, IEnumerable`1 manipulators)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__0(ProjectItem i)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileFinder.FindConfigFiles(ProjectItems items, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.Execute()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.1.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...`enter code here`
Install-Package : This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], RuntimeException
```

Answer (score 1):

When Entity Framework is upgraded, the app.config or web.config files will get stuff written into them. Check your `web.config` file. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964620/error-this-operation-would-create-an-incorrectly-structured-document) the error was

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

which was fixed when the line was changed to

```
<configuration>
```