# The document error for enabling Migration in a Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have just made a Code First model from my DB and now I need to activate migrations on the application.However when I type "enable-migrations" in the Nuget package manager I recieve this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document. at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter).....

I would be very appreciated, if you can help me to manage this problem please.

Comment: Can you include web.config contents? `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument` usually means there's something wrong happened in configuration file (i.e. web.config). Check if wrong value assigned in `configuration` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks To : [This operation would create an incorrectly structured document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964620/error-this-operation-would-create-an-incorrectly-structured-document/21681056#21681056)

just remove `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"` in `configuration` tag in `web.config`.