# Error while running Enable-Migrations in Visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to migrate my web app from membership to ASP.Net Identity by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity#getting-started). But I get this error when I execute the Enable-migrations command:

> Blockquote 
>   PM> Enable-migrations
>   System.ArgumentException: Paramètre incorrect. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      à EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
>      à System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      à System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      à System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      à System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      à EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
>      à System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
>      à System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
>      à System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
>      à System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      à System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   Paramètre incorrect. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I tried with the parameters -ProjectName and -StartUpProjectName but it does not work. I use EntityFramework 6.2.0. Need help please.

Comment: What does your solution structure look like?   Are your classes for your models separated into a different project than the web app?

Comment: @user1011627, all my classes are in the same project

Comment: Can you show the actual commands you are attempting to run?

Comment: Also, do you have a "globalization" section in web.config for the project?

Comment: `enable-migrations -ProjectName myApp`  and  `enable-migrations -StartUpProjectName myApp`. myApp is the name of the project.

Comment: there is no globalization section in web.config

Comment: OK...commands look ok, but since they are in the same project you shouldn't need to include the project name and startup project params.   In doing some research, it looks like any configuration issue in web.config can cause this error.  The globalization section was also posted elsewhere as a known culprit.  Can you verify that your web.config is valid and does not contain any duplicate sections?   Based on what I am seeing, the web.config is likely the cause.

Comment: Also, have you tried running the code with the verbose flag?

Comment: I tried `enable-migrations -Verbose` but it doesn't work. There is no duplicate code in the web.config. It is true that I had trouble installing EF because it was necessary to delete xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0" from the configuration tag and put it back after installation. But I don't know if that's the problem

Comment: I'd say your last comment is the root of all your evils...have you tried to run the migration command without the namespace?

Comment: Check out this SO question/answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964620/error-this-operation-would-create-an-incorrectly-structured-document

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, I finally created a library a c# in my project (select your project then file-> new project-> visual c# -> class library). I made the migrations in this library and I added it as a reference to my project and it worked.